# Why can I not get the correct value of some custom-defined Tag in Metrics?

Tags: metrics

I posted a question in the github of Metrics.NET--https://github.com/Recognos/Metrics.NET/issues/66.

I am waiting for an answer. Could you answer here or in the github?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-post of a GitHub issue.

Comment: OP, if you want a question to be considered here, please post it here. You can (and should) still link to other places you have posted it, but the link on its own is not sufficient.